# Unable to create column which looks for text string in Python

Tags: python, string, associations

I have run association rules on my data set, now I have my list of values (Support, confidence, lift, etc) and want to filter my antecedents to just one of my original values to see the relationship it has with the others. I have tried to create a new column in the data that looks to see if the string "Engagement Score" appears in the antecedents column, but I just get a NaN error in my new column.

I have tried `str.match` and `str.contains`, but get the same error:

```
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

data = pd.read_csv('HR - YSS Scale.csv')

frequent_itemsets = apriori(data, min_support = 0.05, use_colnames = True)
frequent_itemsets.sort_values('support', ascending = False)

rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric = 'confidence',   
min_threshold = 0.6)

rules["anc is eng"] = rules["antecedents"].str.match('Engagement Score')
rules["anc is eng"] = rules["anc is eng"].map({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})

rules.sort_values('confidence', ascending = False)
```

I want a new column that says Yes or No if the antecedent in that row is "Engagement Score". Currently I just get `NaN` error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a minimum reproducible example.  Your code seems like it should work, but its hard to tell and also we don't know what "confidence" is

Comment: Updated the code now - thanks

Comment: I still can't reproduce as I don't have your original data